# C# .NET Core application cannot open serial port

Tags: raspbian, serial, uart, raspberry-pi-os

I'm running a .NET Core application on Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit Debian).

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

The console app uses a `standard2.0` classlib DLL to access a device via UART0. UART0 should be accessible via `/dev/ttyAMA0`. I'm using [`System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0). The serial console is disabled, the serial port is enabled (`raspi-config`). However if I try to initialize the driver with pseudo-code like this one

```
_serialPort = new SerialPort();
_serialPort.PortName = "/dev/ttyAMA0";
_serialPort.PortName = SetPortName(_serialPort.PortName);
// set properties
_serialPort.Open();
```

I'm getting

`Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The port is closed.`

Comment: What Pi? What `/etc/os-release`?  Why not `/dev/serial0`?

Comment: I've added the releaase info. Ah, thanks. I've found `/dev/ttyAMA0` in some example code in the wild. However `/dev/serial0` makes a lot more sense.